# How I can get enum data type in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

I want to get all enum data type from Mysql database. remember a thing that my table have no data.  I read some other post but they have not specific answer as I want. Please someone can help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get enum possible values in a MySQL database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350052/how-can-i-get-enum-possible-values-in-a-mysql-database)

Comment: I have blank table and hope it's not worked for me.

Comment: The table can be empty, but enum values cannot be empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get enum possible values in a MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350052/how-can-i-get-enum-possible-values-in-a-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0):

I do so:

`SELECT DISTINCT(data_type) FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS`WHERE table_schema =<Your database>`

[INFORMATION_SCHEMA Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-schema.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query to get all ENUM values -

```
SELECT
  TRIM(TRAILING ')' FROM TRIM(LEADING '(' FROM TRIM(LEADING 'enum' FROM column_type))) enun_values
FROM
  information_schema.`COLUMNS`
WHERE
  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name' AND
  TABLE_NAME = 'table_name' AND
  COLUMN_NAME = 'col_name';
```