# SonataAdmin: generate form fields for enum?

Tags: symfony, php-5.3, sonata-admin

Is there any default way to make Sonata Admin generate form fields for mysql enums as a choice of some sort? Radio buttons, select, whatever, i.e. *not* a text field where user can enter whatever he wants? It treats them like strings now, rendering input text field.

I have my enums defined this way:

```
myProperty:
    type: enum
    length: 10
    column: my_property
    columnDefinition: ENUM('yeah', 'whatever')
```

and they are "real" enums, i.e. my_property column is of mySQL enum type in the database.

I'd prefer a solution that doesn't require me to hardcode enum values into Sonata's Admin.php file, if possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to do it is using a choice field and you can provide choices with an array that you get from databases.

Here's an [example function for codeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350052/how-can-i-get-enum-possible-values-in-a-mysql-database) and you can write the same for Symfony2.

So in your admin class you can add your field to the form like this:

```
    $formMapper->add('my_property',
                'choice',
                 array('choices' => MyEnitity::get_enum_values('my_property') );
```

Make sure to provide keys for the array because sonata will use them as as values.

Comment: would it be nice if someone translated this example in actual Symfony code :D

Comment: Sorry I haven't used Symfony in years :)