# php split mysql field type into parts with preg_replace

Tags: php, mysql

I have a string... ENUM('0','1')

and I want to get an array... array('ENUM', array(0, 1));

and I want to do it with preg_replace instead of using multiple complicated explode statements
like so...

```
$showColumns = 'SHOW COLUMNS FROM table';
if (strpos($show[$k][1], '(')!==FALSE) {
    $showType = explode("(", $show[$k][1]);//PREG_SPLIT IS BETTER
}
$elementType = strtoupper($showType[0]);
$type = $this->FIELD_TYPE[$elementType];

$vals = explode(")", $showType[1]);
if (is_integer($vals[0])) {
    $values = $vals[0];
}elseif (strpos($vals[0], ',')!==FALSE) {
    $vs = explode(',', $vals[0]);
    $vs = array_map('str_replace', $vs, array('\'', '', $vs[0])); 
    $values=array();
    foreach ($vs as $v) {
        $values[] = $v;
    }
}

$values = $vals[0];
print $values; print '<br /><br />';
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get enum possible values in a MySQL database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350052/how-can-i-get-enum-possible-values-in-a-mysql-database)

Comment: not duplicate, specifically looking the regular expression that while match any of the following int(num), enum(array), text(str) and give me back two values, the part before the parenthesis and the part inside the parenthesis, I don't want to match enum here I want to split the string using the parenthesis

Comment: what is the end result you are trying to get? What should this `print $values; print '<br /><br />';` show?

Comment: if the string is int(10) i want two variables, first value "int" second value "10"