# MySQL ENUM column type

Tags: mysql, sql

Can i get all possibilities of enum column type by one query?

For example, i have column colors with possibilities 'red', 'green', 'blue'.

I want to get something like this:

```
colors
------
red
green
blue
```

or

```
colors
------
red, green, blue
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get enum possible values in a MySQL database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350052/how-can-i-get-enum-possible-values-in-a-mysql-database)

Comment: There is no useful solution for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to get the actual values present in this column, try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT color FROM colorenum
```

If you are going to get all values that are allowed for this column, try:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM colorenum WHERE Field = 'color'
```

see example here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d27350/1

or

```
SELECT COLUMN_TYPE 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME='colorenum' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'COLOR';
```

This one will return `enum('red','green','blue','white','yellow','black')` for example.

or

```
SELECT REPLACE(
  (REPLACE(
    (REPLACE(
      (REPLACE(
        (SELECT COLUMN_TYPE 
         FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
         WHERE TABLE_NAME='colorenum' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'COLOR')
      , 'enum(', '')),
    ')', '')),
  '\'', '')),
',', ', ');
```

This one will return `red, green, blue, white, yellow, black` for example.

Comment: The last one is best for me to use. Thank you.