# Get the name of next enum field's value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, enums, enumeration

I have an MySQL database and a table `table1` with columns:

- `id` of *uint* type
- some other, not important now fields (like `name`, `age` etc.),
- `status` of *enum* type `(met, like, love, hate, kill)`.

For the inserted row `(1, love)`, i want to select the "next" `status` (`hate`).

**My attempt:**

I tried:

```
SELECT (status + 1) FROM table1 WHERE id = 1
```

but it retured `4` (index, not text value).

Of course:

```
SELECT status FROM table1 WHERE id = 1
```

returns `love` (text value, not index).

**Question:**

Is there an way to achive it (some kind of "casting" maybe)?

I preffer solution that **do not mess with database schema tables**.

Also, I could `UPDATE` that row with `status = status + 1`, than select it and after it `UPDATE` again with `status = status - 1`, but it's even worse idea...

**Edit**

As I have been asked to give some more details:
I do not have any additional table that hold the order of my enum. I just added it with `phpMyAdmin`, and the selection from it works as I described.
Moreover when I update the table with `status = status + 1` i get `hate` from `love`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM test 
WHERE status+0=(SELECT (status + 0)+1 FROM test   WHERE id = 1)
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33d79/6)

Here is the next status

```
SELECT (status + 0)+1 FROM test WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: Ok, but it works only if value "hate" has been insterted in the table. I have only one row which I mentioned. And I cannot assume there will be all possible values of enum type in my table every time.

Comment: So whats the problem:you want to select the id and status even if its not there?

Comment: Close. But only the status. Preciselly: what will be the *next* status of field with given id (but without updating it).

Comment: But the "here is the next status" return number not value and it's the same like what I wrote in my post (section "I tried"). My problem is to convert that returned "4" to "hate".

Comment: Create a separate table with the respective enum,populated with all possibilities and get the enum from there.I dont see other way.

Comment: Kind of creepy way ;) When I would change the enum possible values, I would also had to change that extra table (that exists only to select next value of enum). Still thx for pointing some idea.

Comment: Like this,is fairly easy if you dont have a gigantic enum http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/daa30/2

Comment: OR,get in application code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350052/how-can-i-get-enum-possible-values-in-a-mysql-database

Answer (score 1):

That is no that easy as you might think. How do you manage the order of your enum? Via ID? Via an ordering column? At least you have to work with sub-queries or something like that. Could you give us some more detailed information?