# PHPActiveRecord Find Column Names & Types & In Particular ENUM Components

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpactiverecord

Is there a way to get all the column names, and then figure out **what type the column is**? For example, ENUM, VARCHAR, TINYINT, etc..., in particular for ENUM the different components of the ENUM?

I found something here (http://www.phpactiverecord.org/docs/ActiveRecord/Column)

Not sure how to get the type though from this documentation?

Comment: The answer by byte255 is very close, I only need to figure out the ENUM values now instead of it just returning type ENUM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list column names and their types:

```
$columns = MyModel::table()->columns;
foreach ($columns as $column) {
    echo "{$column->name} - {$column->raw_type} <br>\n";
}
```

Where `MyModel` is the name of your model class.

This will output "raw" database type as defined in the DB schema.
You can also use `$column->type` for normalized type in ActiveRecord internal representation.

See AR source [here](https://github.com/jpfuentes2/php-activerecord/blob/master/lib/Table.php#L26) and [here](https://github.com/jpfuentes2/php-activerecord/blob/master/lib/Connection.php#L261).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This worked great and helps a lot so far.  I did get that the value was ENUM... but I unfortunately did not get the values that make up the ENUM.  Lets say the ENUM was made up of values such as 'Yes', 'No', 'Maybe', I need to figure out what those are.

Comment: As opposed to the current answer which just returns ENUM.  None the less this is a great start for me to explore into.* - forgot to add this into last comment.

Comment: @JosephAstrahan Unfortunately PHP ActiveRecord doesn't parse ENUM values, [see the source](https://github.com/jpfuentes2/php-activerecord/blob/master/lib/adapters/MysqlAdapter.php#L33). So there is no list of values readily available. However, you can issue SHOW COLUMNS statement and parse the ENUM values yourself, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350052/how-can-i-get-enum-possible-values-in-a-mysql-database).