# Get enum options in laravels eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, enums, eloquent

In my migration file, I gave my table `pages` a `enum` field with 2 possible values (as seen below). My question is, if it's possible to select these values with Laravels **Eloquent**?

```
$table->enum('status', array('draft','published'));
```

There are several Workarounds that I found, but there must be some "eloquent-native" way to handle this. My expected output would be this (that would be perfect!):

```
array('draft','published')
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 25):

Unfortunately, Laravel does not offer a solution for this. You will have to do it by yourself. I did some digging and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350052/how-can-i-get-enum-possible-values-in-a-mysql-database)

You can use that function and turn it into a method in your model class...

```
class Page extends Eloquent {

    public static function getPossibleStatuses(){
        $type = DB::select(DB::raw('SHOW COLUMNS FROM pages WHERE Field = "type"'))[0]->Type;
        preg_match('/^enum\((.*)\)$/', $type, $matches);
        $values = array();
        foreach(explode(',', $matches[1]) as $value){
            $values[] = trim($value, "'");
        }
        return $values;
    }
}
```

And you use it like this

```
$options = Page::getPossibleStatuses();
```

If you want you can also make it a bit more universally accessible and generic.

First, create a `BaseModel`. All models should then extend from this class

```
class BaseModel extends Eloquent {}
```

After that, put this function in there

```
public static function getPossibleEnumValues($name){
    $instance = new static; // create an instance of the model to be able to get the table name
    $type = DB::select( DB::raw('SHOW COLUMNS FROM '.$instance->getTable().' WHERE Field = "'.$name.'"') )[0]->Type;
    preg_match('/^enum\((.*)\)$/', $type, $matches);
    $enum = array();
    foreach(explode(',', $matches[1]) as $value){
        $v = trim( $value, "'" );
        $enum[] = $v;
    }
    return $enum;
}
```

You call this one like that

```
$options = Page::getPossibleEnumValues('status');
```

Comment: Why not use a dedicated trait for this?

Comment: Sure you can use a trait if you want

Comment: Laravel should add this to every Eloquent Class maybe as a Trait

Comment: I tried this solution, yes it works but how can I save the Index instead of the status itself. Example 1 for 'draft', then 2 for 'published'

Answer (score 5):

Made a small improvement to lukasgeiter's function.  The foreach loop in his answer is parsing the string.  You can update the regex to do that for you.

```
/**
 * Retrieves the acceptable enum fields for a column
 *
 * @param string $column Column name
 *
 * @return array
 */
public static function getPossibleEnumValues ($column) {
    // Create an instance of the model to be able to get the table name
    $instance = new static;

    // Pulls column string from DB
    $enumStr = DB::select(DB::raw('SHOW COLUMNS FROM '.$instance->getTable().' WHERE Field = "'.$column.'"'))[0]->Type;

    // Parse string
    preg_match_all("/'([^']+)'/", $enumStr, $matches);

    // Return matches
    return isset($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : [];
}
```

Comment: This throws an error if the column does not have enum values. So I added a small check in the code

`
public static function getPossibleEnumValues ($column) {
    // Create an instance of the model to be able to get the table name
    $instance = new static;

    // Pulls column string from DB
    $enumStr = $arr[0]->Type;

    // Parse string
    preg_match_all("/'([^']+)'/", $enumStr, $matches);

    // Return matches
    return isset($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : [];
}
`

Answer (score 3):

This throws an error if the column does not exist. So I added a small check in the code

```
public static function getPossibleEnumValues ($column) {
// Create an instance of the model to be able to get the table name
    $instance = new static;

    $arr = DB::select(DB::raw('SHOW COLUMNS FROM '.$instance->getTable().' WHERE Field = "'.$column.'"'));
    if (count($arr) == 0){
        return array();
    }
    // Pulls column string from DB
    $enumStr = $arr[0]->Type;

    // Parse string
    preg_match_all("/'([^']+)'/", $enumStr, $matches);

    // Return matches
    return isset($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : [];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As of L5.17 Eloquent does not include this functionality, instead you need to fall back to native QL. Here's an example that will work with SQL and in one line - returning an array like you asked.

In the spirit of one liner complexity ;)

I threw this in one of my view composers - it fetches the column from the table, explodes it and assembles the values in an array.

I iterate over that in my views using a foreach.

```
explode (
    "','",
    substr (
      DB::select("  SHOW COLUMNS 
                    FROM ".(new \Namespace\Model)->getTable()." 
                    LIKE 'colName'"
      )[0]->Type,
      6,
      -2
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**`If you are here in 2023.`**

It has been stated in one of the answers provided by @lukasgeiter and edited by @petemir. Laravel doesn't have a workaround for enums straight out of the box, in other ways, PHP in itself started supporting ENUM in version 8.1.

The easiest workaround is to use a Laravel package. There are a few you can use but I have used Besampo Laravel-enum whenever the thought of enums comes into mind.

[Bensampo Laravel-enum](https://github.com/BenSampo/laravel-enum)