# MYSQL Ordering an array

Tags: mysql, arrays

This is my result

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING(COLUMN_TYPE,5)                                                                                                                     |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ('Sedan','Hatch','Convertable','Van','Coupe','Light Truck','People Mover','SUV','Ute','Wagon','Cab Chassis','Sample Body','Body 4','BOdy 5') |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This is my query

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(COLUMN_TYPE,5) FROM information_schema.COLUMNS  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE()  AND TABLE_NAME='Ad_tbl'  AND COLUMN_NAME='body_type'
```

I want the array to be ordered the other way.. So the Sedan would be in the last of the array instead of first.. Already Tried ORDER BY either ASC or DESC but no luck

Comment: ORDER BY `COLUMN_TYPE` DESC. Using DESC instead of ASC will sort it the other way.

Comment: I updated the query,, actually ORDER BY doesn't take effect whether I set it to ASC or DESC

Comment: Take a look on [**ORDER BY FIELD**] [http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/109120/how-does-order-by-field-in-mysql-work-internally]

Comment: ORDER BY does not work

Comment: The result you provided seems not the result of your  query .. you have substring of 5 and the result  seem a group_concat .. ????

Comment: That is the result of the query.. But I want that array result to be in a reverse order

Comment: since on of your tags is php, you could also reverse the order in php, when you put the whole thing into an array. (array_reverse)

Comment: @Jakumi, I am actually avoiding that

Comment: Then you probably shouldn't tag your question php... anyway. Order by could be called on ordinal_position?

Comment: @Jakumi Can you write a query example?

Comment: oh wait, misread your query. Do I understand correctly, that you're querying the column information for an enum field?

Comment: I fear there's no clean solution in mysql only, that I can think of. Apart from changing the database schema to make the enum field a foreign key of another table, that just contains the values of the enum. In php it would be quite easy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350052/how-can-i-get-enum-possible-values-in-a-mysql-database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're querying the list of items in an `ENUM` definition, and you want to change the order? You can't do that without using `ALTER TABLE` to change your `ENUM`.

The order of items in an `ENUM` is related to the physical storage of the values. 'Sedan' is 1, 'Hatch' is 2, 'Convertable' (sic) is 3, etc. Changing the order of these strings requires changing the enumeration values.

Of course, you could change the order of displaying the strings in your application code. But this means parsing out the items from that list, splitting on comma, removing quotes and parens, etc.

But doing similar text-parsing in pure SQL will be an exercise in frustration, or at least, it'll be a huge waste of time.

This awkwardness of fetching the items in an `ENUM` definition is one of the reasons [MySQL's ENUM data type is evil](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/).

If you want to control the sort order without redefining the table,
you'll be better off using a lookup table instead of an `ENUM`.

Comment: Ok noted on this one