# How to get enum field value by its index in mysql

Tags: mysql, enums

I have a table with an enum field. I need to calculate average value of this field and show it as one of enum elements.

I'm getting the average like this: `SELECT AVG(val) FROM test;` It works fine. But then I need to get one of enum values back by this index. To get index I'm using `ROUND`. But I don't know what to do next.

Is it possible?

Is there some other approach?

### Example

Create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    val ENUM('bad', 'good', 'perfect')
);
```

Fill the table:

```
INSERT INTO test(val) VALUES('bad'), ('bad'), ('good'), ('bad'), ('perfect'), ('perfect'), ('good');
```

Select query to be fixed somehow:

```
SELECT AVG(val) average_value_ind, ROUND(AVG(val)) closest_value_ind FROM test;
```

In this example the average value should be `good`

Comment: Another approach? Yes; don't use ENUM.

Comment: I'm not responsible for this table and can't change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers and comments. You've helped me.

Here what I've managed to do. It works in my case.

```
SELECT 
    AVG(val) average_value, 
    ROUND(AVG(val)) closest_value_id, 
    JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(val_enum.items, CONCAT("$[", ROUND(AVG(val)) - 1, "]"))) enum_value
FROM test
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT CAST(CONCAT('[', REPLACE(SUBSTRING(COLUMN_TYPE, 6, LENGTH(COLUMN_TYPE) - 6), "'", '"'), ']') AS JSON) items
    FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'test' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'val'
) val_enum;
```

Comment: Check `SCHEMA_NAME` in the subquery too for to avoid that there exists the table `test` with the column `val` in another database.

Comment: That is horrible and yet strangely beautiful at the same time... :-)

Comment: @Nick yes, I wish there would be a better way to do this ;)

Answer (score 2):

While it's easy to convert `ENUM` values into integers or strings, it's harder to go the other way. You can use the [`ELT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_elt) function but that requires enumerating all the `ENUM` values:

```
SELECT AVG(val) average_value_ind, 
       ELT(ROUND(AVG(val)), 'bad', 'good', 'perfect') closest_value_ind 
FROM test;
```

Output:

```
average_value_ind   closest_value_ind
1.8571428571428572  good
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cc78f6e82d0dc9ca03fa4e8bc8d32b62)

Comment: Can you somehow generate the list by querying metadata?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Of course this is possible (for example you may query and parse INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLUMN_TYPE).

Comment: @BoristheSpider see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350052/how-can-i-get-enum-possible-values-in-a-mysql-database for some possible solutions. In theory you could join `information_schema.COLUMNS` to get the information but in many instances users don't have access to those tables.

Comment: *in many instances users don't have access to those tables* This is strange and unjustifiable restriction... except for the laziness of the administrator, who is easier to deny access to the INFORMATION_SCHEMA at all than to give the privilege for SELECT only to INFORMATION_SCHEMA which is a couple of views, not tables.

Comment: @Akina I'm not saying it's not unjustifiable, or that administrators are lazy, but it has been my experience...